# Convert Bit String To Array in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, bitstring

I have a 160 chars bit string and I need to have an integer array that stores the position of the bits that have a value of 1.

Example:

```
bitstring = '00110101'
array = [3,4,6,8]
```

Is it possible to do this just with SQL or do I need to define a PL/SQL function or something like that?

Comment: The position count starts at 1, not at 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's assuredly possible to write it in SQL. Here's a starting point:

```
select array(
  select substring(str from i for 1) as bit
  from generate_series(1, length(str)) as i
  where bit = '1'
);
```

You might want to wrap that in a pl/sql function regardless, though, so to avoid duplicating code all over the place.

---

Working function:

```
create or replace function get_bit_positions(varbit) returns bit[] as $$
select array(
  select substring($1 from i for 1) as bit
  from generate_series(1, length($1)) as i
  where substring($1 from i for 1) = '1'
);
$$ language sql immutable;
```

Comment: @Topo: This answer does not work. Illegal reference to a column aliases in the `WHERE` clause, illegal reference to `str`. Why would you accept it? BTW: pl/sql is the name of Oracle's procedural language. Probably plpgsql.

Comment: pl/sql is also the name of plain sql functions in postgres.

Comment: Those are just called "SQL functions". There is no PL/SQL in PostgreSQL. "PL" is reserved for procedural languages.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I know it does not runs, but I just had to change the `bit` in the last line for `substring($1 from i for 1)`. I accepted the answer because it answered the question, it was only the syntax that was wrong

Comment: @Topo: If you found the answer needed improvements to make it work, don't just silently accept the broken version. Other people will find it and waste their time in wonder why it wouldn't work for them. Give feedback or fix the answer. As you can see, Denis happily improved his answer.

Answer (score 6):

Working version:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT '00110101'::varbit AS b)
SELECT array_agg(i)
FROM  (SELECT b, generate_series(1, length(b)) AS i FROM x) y
WHERE  substring(b, i, 1) = '1';
```

Simpler once you convert the `varbit` to `text[]`. Cast to `text` and run [`string_to_array()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html).

Then you can use [`generate_subscripts()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) and pick array elements by index:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT string_to_array('00110101'::varbit::text, NULL) AS b)
SELECT array_agg(i)
FROM  (SELECT b, generate_subscripts(b,1) AS i FROM x) y
WHERE b[i] = '1'
```

Details in [this related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-do-i-preserve-the-order-of-the-original-elements-in-an-unnested-array).